# request.POST.get [] is empty

Tags: django

I am trying to create a site with only registered users have access.i used a simple sign up form to get username and password to create the user.The post data cannot be retreived using request.POST.get .They are empty.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    uname = request.POST.get('username')
    upass = request.POST.get('pass') ....                                                          

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',)
```

Comment: Are they present in your submitted form?

Comment: try `request.body` or `request.body.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests) about this topic, you will find a lot of important notes too. You can use inbuilt login view - [django.contrib.auth.views.login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) to handle authentication stuff for you but you have to prepare the template.

If the given POST variable is empty, you didn't submitted the variable in your form so check your html code in tools like Firebug

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be you are trying to perform an authentication in your view. You can use `@login_required` decorator. More info at 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what it is you're trying to do. If you're trying to get details of the user in your django view then you can use request.user. eg

```
def your_view(request):
    #...
    user = request.user
    return render(request, 'your_page.html')
```

Have a look at the [user auth docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests).